# Probability question regarding $3$ pairs of boxes with different objects

Tags: probability

Suppose there are two boxes each containing an eraser, another two boxes each containing a pencil, and another two boxes each containing a pen. The boxes are not labelled, and we need at least one eraser, one pen, and one pencil from the boxes. Let $N$ be the number of boxes that have to be opened to meet the requirements. What is the probability that i) $N=4$ ii) $N=5$.

I think that once $\operatorname{Prob}(N=4)$ is found, we can automatically find $\operatorname{Prob}(N=5)$. This is because the only possible values of $N$ are $3$, $4$, $5$ [$N$ can't be $2$ because we need at least $3$ items, $N$ can't be $6$ because when $5$ boxes are opened we will surely get the items]. Now finding $\operatorname{Prob}(N=3)$ is easy, it is $4/5 \cdot 2/4 = 2/5$ [for $N=3$, each and every box we open has to contain a different object, so after the first box is chosen we cannot choose the other box which has the same object, so we can choose only $4$ balls out of the remaining $5$, and after another box has been chosen $4$ balls are remaining but we can choose only $2$, and thus the probability$= 4/5 \cdot 2/4 = 2/5$]. Now we know that $\operatorname{Prob}(N=3) + \operatorname{Prob}(N=4) + \operatorname{Prob}(N=5) = 1 \implies \operatorname{Prob}(N=4) + \operatorname{Prob}(N= 5) = 3/5$. Hence we can find $\operatorname{Prob}(N=5)$ when $\operatorname{Prob}(N=4)$ is known.

But I am a little stuck in finding $\operatorname{Prob}(N=4)$. Any hints will be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: try to decompose N=4 as: first three draws there are only two distint objects and fourth draw brings one more.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  It is easier to find the probability you need $5$ boxes directly, then derive the probability you only need $4$ from that.  To need $5$ boxes, the two remaining after the first four are picked must contain a matching pair.
If you want to calculate the probability of needing $4$ directly, I would divide it into cases.  You can have the second item match the first, then have the next two not match, or have the first two different, the third matching one of those two, and the fourth be what you need.  This seems harder than calculating $5$.

Comment: Sir I don't believe the last two must contain a matching pair. For example the sequence ABBAC has 5 boxes but the last two pairs don't match. In fact, in a sequence with 5 boxes the last two cannot match, because after the fourth one is filled up we would already have got our requirement so a fifth box won't be needed. Am I right or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @abcd:  By the last two I meant the fifth and sixth boxes.  I agree it wasn't clear-I will clarify.  Thanks.

Comment: I am writing my approach here in this comment. Can you please rectify if I am correct or not?

For the sequence to have 5 boxes, the first four selections have to be of the form AABB, or ABBA, or BABA, or ACCA, etc. In each such sequence only two disinct letters are present. In a particular sequence let these letters be X and Y. X and Y can be chosen in 3 choose 2 =3 ways, and the sequence XXYY can be permuted in 4!/(2!)^2 ways= 6 ways. Hence total number of valid selections= 6*3 = 18. Continued in the next comment.

Comment: @abcd:  the easy approach for $5$ is to line the boxes up in the order you will pick them, then reverse the order.  We require $5$ if the first two of the new order match, which is probability $\frac 15$